# _com_error exception on DirectX Create* methods

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have been trying to get into DirectX programming lately (with C++/Win32), and I encountered some issues.

A friend programmed a very simple random terrain generator that works with Perlin Noise, so I tried to grab his code and make a DirectX 11 renderer for it, but my program throws an "Microsoft C++ Exception", _com_error when I run it.

Even wierder, the program breaks at different lines of code depending on the build type...

On Debug, the program breaks on this chunk of code:

```
// Load the pixel shader
std::ifstream pixelFile("pixel.cso");
if (!pixelFile)
    return false;
std::string pixelContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(pixelFile)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
pixelFile.close();
if (FAILED(mpDevice->CreatePixelShader(pixelContents.c_str(),
    pixelContents.size(),
    NULL,
    &mpPixelShader)))
    return false;
```

And on Release:

```
// Create and set the input layout
if (FAILED(mpDevice->CreateInputLayout(layoutDescription,
    layoutDescriptionSize,
    vertexContents.c_str(),
    vertexContents.length(),
    &mpVertexLayout)))
    return false;
```

mpPixelShader is a member of type ID3D11PixelShader*, and mpVertexLayout is a member of type ID3D11InputLayout*.

Of course, the first thing I thought when I saw that the error was different was checking for memory corruption, and sure enough I found one in my friend's code after running ApplicationVerifier and setting the _crtDbgFlag, but it is fixed now and I still have this error...

The application ran fine when the rendering initialization function was filled with a modified version of the one found on the MSDN Win32 DirectX Triangle Tutorial too.

Answer (score 0):

The cso file is not a text, it is a binary file. A `std::string` will not work, the file will contains bytes that are 0.

Comment: A `std::string` actually works in those cases. It doesn't uses C-style `strlen` for length calculation and `c_str` works just like `&string[0]`, as the data is continguous (at least on GNU and MSVC implementations). Anyway, I still followed your advice and used a std::vector and it still yields the same error, so the issue was not coming from here.